# Need help filtering an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, filter

So this is my array in JavaScript:

```
let myArray = ["Bob", "Katy", "Bob", "Bob", "Katy"];
```

I want to filter this array by checking **if the current value is equal to the value after, OR before it**. I'm not quite sure how to achieve this, however, could anybody point me to a direction?

Right now I know how to use the .filter() method to filter an array according to a condition set on a value, but not sure how to do this with a value, as well as the value at the index before and after it.

This is all I have right now:

```
 let numberOfBobs = myArray.filter(x => x === "Bob");
```

However this isn't what I'm after. **I only want to record numberOfBobs if the "Bob" also has a matching "Bob" before OR afer it.**

Comment: Should the result be 1 or 2?

Comment: Hi so, I'd expect the new array to just include 1 "Bob" (numberOfBobs), because there is only one "Bob" in the array that has a matching name before or after it.

Comment: The second “Bob” has a matching name after it, and the third “Bob” has a matching name before it, no? If the logic is to skip ones that were already used for before/after checks, what happens if there are three in a row?

Comment: Ah yeah you're right, there should be two matches. I figured it out anyway, just used a map to check it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand your use case, but if what you're looking for is, given that example, to obtain the array ['Bob', 'Bob'] (which would be the last 'Bob's when using your filter on ['Bob', 'Katy', 'Bob', 'Bob']), then you can use the index the callback for filter takes, which would be something like:

```js
const filteredArray = myArray.filter((item, index) => {
  // check for border cases, like index 0 and last item
  return item === myArray[index - 1] || item === myArray[index + 1]
})
```

This would add the element to the returned array if it's equal to either previous or next item.

Answer (score -1):

```
let counter = 0;
for(i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    let before  = myArray[i-1];
    let current = myArray[i];
    let after   = myArray[i+1];

    if(current === before || current === after) {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

In your case the outcome for the `counter`would be `2`.